# csv importing latitude column as float need it to be numeric

Tags: python-3.x, floating-point, integer, geo, streamlit

After importing a csv file, i plot it using [streamlit](https://www.streamlit.io/).

The issue is that the column type imported for the lat/long is are float. How do I transform this float into a readable format?

I have tried a few tricks using pd.tu_numeric() or .apply(np.int64) but nothing worked.

```
new_df['latitude'] = data['latitude'].dropna().apply(np.int64)
new_df['longitude'] = data['longitude'].dropna().apply(np.int64)


pd.to_numeric(data, errors='coerce')
st.map(data)
```

Thanks for helping a beginner

Comment: Lat/Lon are generally specified as floats, not integers. Why do you think you need to change to integer?

Comment: Because the streamlit interface tells me
"StreamlitAPIException: Latitude and longitude data must be numeric"

Comment: Converting a float (number) to a number isn't going to fix that error message. I would keep the floats as is, but check to see if you have any missing values in your data. NaN is also "not a number"

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem creating a dataframe from Postgres database. I tried to convert the dataframe column to numeric with the "pd.to_numeric" function and it not worked.

But actually, the dataframe has NAN (null) values, so I needed to remove the NAN values from dataframe:

```py
dataframe = dataframe.dropna()
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html

Answer (score 0):

Try using below snippet

```
new_df['latitude']=pd.to_numeric(new_df['latitude']) 
new_df['longitude']=pd.to_numeric(new_df['longitude])
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html